# Custom sized xy-grid gutters in foundation 6

Tags: css, sass, grid, zurb-foundation, mixins

I am using Foundation 6 with sass. I included the xy-grid by using `@include foundation-xy-grid-classes;`. So far everything is fine.

But I need a grid with smaller margin gutters. I understand that I could overwrite `$grid-margin-gutters` but that would change my gutters globaly.

I need small gutters only for some grids and not on all grids. I also want that all the grid functionality remains the same, just with smaller gutters.

I imagine something like this:

```
<div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x-small grid-margin-y-small">
        <div class="small-6 medium-4 cell" v-for="(entry, index) in data" v-bind:class="{auto : index === (data.length-1)}">
                ...some content... 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Sass:**

```
.grid-margin-x-small {
    @include xy-gutters($gutters: 0.2rem, $negative: true, $gutter-position: (left, right, top, bottom));

    >.cell {
        @include xy-gutters($gutters: 0.2rem, $gutter-position: (left, right, top, bottom));
    }
```

But unfortunately that does not include the right sizes for the cells (they are to wide).

**Can I get the normal grid behoivior but with smaller gutters without overwriting the default grid?**

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to define a whole new grid:

```
.gallery-grid {
    @include xy-grid('horizontal');

    @include xy-grid-layout(3, '.gallery-item');
    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        @include xy-grid-layout(5, '.gallery-item');
    }
    @include breakpoint(large up) {
        @include xy-grid-layout(7, '.gallery-item', true, 15, 'padding');
        @include xy-gutters(15, 'padding', $negative:true);
    }
    .gallery-item {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

This outputs a new grid (block grid in my case) with custom gutters. Try playing with values. Hope this helps